# AngularJS Bootstraps Navbar

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, pug, navbar

I'm trying to have a bootstraps navbar display and remove html elements defendant on data from an angular controller.

I have the following jade code:

```
div.navbar.navbar-fixed-top
    div.navbar-inner
        div.container-fluid(data-ng-controller="NavCtrl")

            a.btn.btn-navbar(data-toggle='collapse', data-target='.nav-collapse')
                span.icon-bar
                span.icon-bar
                span.icon-bar

            div.nav-collapse.collapse
                ul.nav
                    li  
                        a(href='/topics') Topics
                    li(ng-show="curUser.admin")
                        a(href='/users') Users
                    li(ng-show="curUser.admin")
                        a(href='/organizations') Organizations
                    li(ng-show="curUser.admin")
                        a(href='/topicConfs') TopicConfig
                    li.divider
                ul.nav.pull-right
                    {{authenticated}}
                    li.dropdown(ng-show="authenticated")
                        a.dropdown-toggle(role='button', data-toggle='dropdown', href='#') {{curUser.email}}
                            b.caret
                        ul.dropdown-menu(role='menu')
                            li
                                a(href='/users/{{curUser._id}}') Profile
                            li.divider
                            li
                                a.btn(ng-click="logout()") Logout
```

And a controller with the following:

```
function NavCtrl($location, $scope, $rootScope, CurrentUser){
  $scope.curUser = CurrentUser.getUser()
  $scope.authenticated = CurrentUser.isAuthenticated()

  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(){
    $scope.curUser = CurrentUser.getUser()
    $scope.authenticated = CurrentUser.isAuthenticated()
  })


  $scope.logout = function(){
    CurrentUser.logout(function(result){
      $scope.curUser = CurrentUser.getUser()
      $scope.authenticated = CurrentUser.isAuthenticated()
      console.log("authenticated before logout is %j", $scope.authenticated)

      $location.url('/')
    })
  }
}
```

Everything displays properly until the `$scope.authenticated` is set to `false` and `$scope.user` is set to `{}` where none of the ng-show attributes are updated in the nav-bar.

What do I need to do to have the bootstraps nav elements respond to the change in the `$scope` variables?

Comment: Try calling `$scope.$apply()`.

Comment: Thanks.  How do I give you a check as answer?  It be cool if you explain exactly when to use $apply.

Comment: Can you share the complete code as Plunkr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Angular $scope properties are changed "outside" of Angular, `$scope.$apply()` needs to be called to cause Angular to enter its [digest loop](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts#runtime).  Any properties that are projected onto the current view will have $watches, which the digest loop will evaluate.  When a change is detected in one of these $watches, the view is updated.

Examples of "outside" of Angular:

- Browser event callback.  E.g.,
   `element.bind('someEvent', function() {`
       `//need to call scope.$apply in here`
   `})`
- Third-party plugin callback.  E.g., the callback passed to `logout` above.
- Third-party AJAX callback.
- Third-party promise.