# Angular.js: Two-Way data binding across multiple controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this code structure in Angular:

```
app.controller(AlphaCtrl, function(interstellarService){

  $scope.interstellarService = {
    routeToEarth: interstellarService.get('routeToEarth'),
  }

})

app.controller(CentauriCtrl, function(interstellarService){

  $scope.interstellarService = {
    routeToEarth: interstellarService.get('routeToEarth'),
  }
})
```

The Interstellar Service stores in the Browser storage:

```
appServices.factory('interstellarService', function ($rootScope, $localStorage){
    return {
        set: function(entidy, value) {
            $localStorage[entidy] = value;
        },
        get: function(entidy) {
           if ($localStorage[entidy] !== undefined) {
              return $localStorage[entidy];
           } else return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Now when I change in the `AlphaCtrl` the `routeToEarth` property via a setter method I expect the CentauriCtrl to update accordingly, because the data is bound at each controller to the service, as in:

**AlphaCtrl <-- data --> interstellarService <-- data --> CentauriCtrl**

This is what does not work: I want to use and share the value stored in `routeToEarth` in my Centauri-HTML, e.g.

```
<li>
  <a>
    {{interstellarService.routeToearth}} && 'Timetravel' || 'Wormhole' }}
  </a>
</li>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: you should try factory instead

Comment: Ok I updated my code with factory still no work.

Comment: did you set it before in your factory? also, what is this expression supposed to do? can you try just rendering the {{interstellarService.routeToearth}} part?

Comment: I notice this: `app.controller` and `appServices.factory`. So are ur factory and controller in different module? If so, did you inject ur sevice properly?

Comment: @SirBenBenji Take a look at my answer

Comment: @khemry: Yes they are in different module and the appServices are injected properly in into the main app. Thanks for noticing anyway. I noticed now that no matter what `scope.anyVar` I bind into my controller it does not update in my html. Only if I hit `F5` in the Browser, it gets updated. `scope.apply()` comes to mind, but I don't know exactly where to implement it. @NidhishKrishnan: Also I should have mentioned that above is kind of pseudo code, of course I am using quotes. I guess should have copied the whole code over, but it haslot of overhead so I abstracted it. Will look at ur example.

Comment: Hi, I never forget to vote, no need to remember :). Anyway, the core problem is I need any changes to routeToEarth immediately displayed in the html. This is the essence of Angular. The problem is that I have to take the detour over the service, since I am saving in session store. This is a authorisation-specific problem. I want to display authorisation status in a different controller than original and data-bind it to html, so the different contorller and its html displays the status of authentication at any time given. Hope this clarifies it. Your ex. uses console.log, it only works on 'F5'.

Comment: Ok thanks for your efforts but your solution is not working in my case.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make certain changes to get it run.

1. missing of quotes for `AlphaCtrl` and `CentauriCtrl`
2. missed to inject $scope for both the `AlphaCtrl` and `CentauriCtrl`  controllers
3. controllers and service modules were different, you mentioned it as `appServices` for service and `app` for controllers

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/807vhtLp/)**

**Script**

```
var appServices = angular.module('app', ['ngStorage']);

appServices.factory('interstellarService', function ($rootScope, $localStorage) {
    return {
        set: function (entidy, value) {
            $localStorage[entidy] = value;
        },
        get: function (entidy) {
            if ($localStorage[entidy] !== undefined) {
                return $localStorage[entidy];
            } else return false;
        }
    }
});

appServices.controller('AlphaCtrl', function (interstellarService, $scope) {
    interstellarService.set('routeToEarth', 'Alpha');
    $scope.interstellarService = {
        routeToEarth: interstellarService.get('routeToEarth'),
    }
    console.log('AlphaCtrl value::', $scope.interstellarService);
})

appServices.controller('CentauriCtrl', function (interstellarService, $scope) {
    interstellarService.set('routeToEarth', 'Centauri');
    $scope.interstellarService = {
        routeToEarth: interstellarService.get('routeToEarth'),
    }
    console.log('CentauriCtrl value::', $scope.interstellarService);
})
```

**Html**

```
<div ng-controller="AlphaCtrl">
    {{interstellarService.routeToEarth}}
</div>
<div ng-controller="CentauriCtrl">
    {{interstellarService.routeToEarth}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting this into my `CentauriCtrl` finally showed the route to earth immeadiately when I change it in `AlphaCtrl`.

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){

         $scope.interstellarService = {
             routeToEarth: interstellarService.get('routeToEarth'),
         }
    });
```

Tribute to this SO Question: [AngularJS Bootstraps Navbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15672278/angularjs-bootstraps-navbar)