# Show bootstrap navbar and apply routing feature after login in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

```
I am getting empty page error whenever I click navigation menu URL shows me
```

I am using angularjs routing feature

Comment: http://localhost/myapp/#!/#%2FviewStudents - my url shows me this error %2

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ash3317/uykb9qh0 -jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Simply put 'routerLink' in the menu anchor tag in your file.component.html

```
    <li routerLinkActive="active">
      <a [routerLink]="[menu.URL]"><i class="fa fa-link"></i> <span>{{menu.Name}}</span></a>
    </li>
```

and don't forget to import Routes and RouterModule:

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
```

Comment: Hello JMS i am using angular 1 and I am routing using authentication to bootstrap navbar page

Comment: maybe this link would be useful - [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15672278/angularjs-bootstraps-navbar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15672278/angularjs-bootstraps-navbar)

Comment: Hey JMS check my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ash3317/uykb9qh0  where I am trying to navigate to another page using Angular JS routing when I click on page getting no page and url apend with http://localhost/myapp/#!/#%2FviewStudents like empty space between URL name viewstudents